# checkbox change event with id contains partial string in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 checkbox with id contains common string in the middle part, how can i get the change event of that checkbox in jquery

id is like
ctl00_MainContent_rblForm8850_0 and ctl00_MainContent_rblForm8850_1

can anybody help me to get solved.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Show us your html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]).on('change', function(event){
  var myId = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(myId);
});
```